# Problems downgrading from pgadmin 4.30 to 4.29

Tags: pgadmin, downgrade

I ran into a significant issue with 4.30 in that many of the function keys dont work. It has been reported as a bug.  I uninstalled 4.30 and re-installed 4.29.  Now the PGAdmin splash screen appears, but PGAdmin never starts in the browser.  I tried going back to 4.28 with no success.  I even tried uninstalling and searching and removing references in RegEdit with no success.  Eventually, I reinstalled 4.30 again and PG Admin appears in the browser but of course I am stuck with the function key issue.

Any ideas on how to downgrade to 4.29.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, PG Admin 5.0 was released today and it solves all my problems.